# F# unit tests and assertion on pattern matching

Tags: f#, xunit

I began to do the bowling kata (http://codingdojo.org/kata/Bowling/) in F#. I wrote a first unit test :

```
[<Fact>]
let ``If no roll was made then the current frame should be the first one`` () =
    let game = newGame()
    let cf = currentFrame game
    match cf with
    | TenthFrame _ -> Assert.True(false)
    | Frame frame ->
        let (firstFrames, _) = deconstructGame game
        Assert.Equal (frame, List.item 0 firstFrames)
```

The test passes, but the "Assert.True(false)" part seems ugly to me... Is there a better way to write it ?

Comment: See [xunit docs](https://xunit.github.io/docs/comparisons.html#assertions) it looks like there isn't an `Assert.Fail ()` method. Your solution seems fine.

Comment: OK, thanks for the link. I expected a more elegant or functional way to write such code. Post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: [Expecto](https://github.com/haf/expecto) has `isFalse`.

Comment: You could define a function with a slightly nicer name: `let failTest msg = Assert.True(false, msg)`, and then use it in your test cases: `match cf with | TenthFrame _ -> failTest "Should be on first frame, not tenth"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://xunit.github.io/docs/comparisons.html#assertions). xunit doesn't provide a method like `Assert.Fail ()`. The suggestion is to use `Assert.True (false, "message")` similar to the way that you are doing.

Comment: I will also give a try to Expecto, thanks to @s952163